# Yahoo.util.connect.asyncRequest POST with callback STOPPED WORKING SUDDENLY

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, yui, yahoo-api

I am using Yahoo.util.connect.asyncRequest POST with callback.

but it stopped working suddenly on UAT environment giving 500 internal server error as "Page not found"

However same code is working fine on dev environment.

It seems Ajax call is failing and not able to reach targeted page. In Firefox and chrome  It giving 500 error as page not available. 
Is it failing to some security setting in UAT server ( Window 2018) ? How do I log root cause of failure with Yahoo.util.connect.asyncRequest POST with callback.

Comment: I would suggest you try using browser tools to debug and analyze what is happening. Also, use server logs to understand if the request is even getting to it.

Comment: Ajax call request is not getting to server side. becoz log is not getting created at server side entry method. Browser developer tool is giving general error as "Page not available".  Is restart of server will work here